# How can I make this Wasm function easily readable in it's native language?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have the following Wasm function I am trying to understand which I believe is some kind of webgl fragment shader:

```
func $frag_shader (param i32)
(local i32 i32 i32 i32 i32)
  global.get 0
  i32.const 32
  i32.sub
  local.tee 1
  global.set 0
  local.get 1
  i32.const 16
  i32.add
  i32.const 1049267
  i32.const 85
  call 23
  local.get 1
  i32.load offset=16 align=4
  local.set 2
  block
    block
      block
        block
          local.get 1
          i32.load offset=20 align=4
          local.tee 3
          local.get 1
          i32.load offset=24 align=4
          local.tee 4
          i32.ne
          br_if 0
          local.get 2
          local.set 5
          local.get 3
          local.set 4
          br 1
        end
        local.get 3
        local.get 4
        i32.lt_u
        br_if 1
        block
          local.get 4
          br_if 0
          i32.const 0
          local.set 4
          i32.const 1
          local.set 5
          local.get 3
          i32.eqz
          br_if 1
          local.get 2
          call 61
          br 1
        end
        local.get 2
        local.get 3
        i32.const 1
        local.get 4
        call 52
        local.tee 5
        i32.eqz
        br_if 2
      end
      local.get 1
      i32.const 8
      i32.add
      local.get 5
      local.get 4
      call 49
      local.get 0
      local.get 1
      i64.load offset=8 align=8
      i64.store offset=0 align=4
      local.get 1
      i32.const 32
      i32.add
      global.set 0
      return
    end
    i32.const 1049136
    call 25
    unreachable
  end
  local.get 4
  i32.const 1
  i32.const 0
  i32.load offset=1050388 align=4
  local.tee 1
  i32.const 1
  local.get 1
  select
  call_indirect 4
  unreachable
end
```

I am familiar with javascript but this to me is undecipherable. What is my best bet to work out how to convert it into more "friendly" javascript?

Is there a tool to help convert to a better format? Or is there a way to understand it more easily?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking for a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), a tool that turns low-level code produced by a compiler back into source-level code. Decompilers are often used for reverse engineering.

I am not aware of any decompilers currently existing for Wasm. Moreover, you would first need to know or guess the source language in which this code was originally developed.

Answer (score -1):

So what you have is something similar to WAT, which is the WASM text format.
However it is not valid WAT, so I am not sure what you can do with it.

If it had been valid WAT, you could have used wat2wasm in the [WebAssembly Binary Toolkit](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) to turn the WAT into binary WASM, and then wasm2c to turn it into C which would be semi readable.

<s>However the way that the BLOCK and END block as are defined is nonstandard (AFAIK , I am not a WASM expert).  And even if I try to replace BLOCK and END with open and close parenthesis, it is still not valid.
So I don't really have an answer for you, except try find out what format the file is really in, and use an appropriate toolset.</s> [ In the comments, Andreas Rossberg explains that block and end are indeed valid keywords  ]

Comment: Why does this answer have -1 votes? It seems accurate

Comment: @fachtna Simi, these things happen sometime on SO. It might be someone who down voted by mistake or because the genuinely felt the answer was wrong. If the had any specific knowledge on the topic however, they should have commented along with their down vote to indicate what was wrong about the answer. You are free to upvote or accept this or any answer that you feel was helpful to you.

Comment: This syntax _is_ valid Wasm text format. It uses instructions in unfolded form. It is merely missing the surrounding module boilerplate.

Comment: @Andreas Rossberg. As I said, I am not an WASM expert - but I cannot get that code to compile, even with added boiler plate.   Are you saying that the BLOCK and END keywords are valid in standard WASM Text Format?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, ok thanks.  You wouldn't happen to have any good resource where the text format is explained in layman's terms?     Also, if this is valid code, then wouldn't the chain wat2wasm -> wasm2c be an option for OP (I mean I think we all realize there are  limitations to readability etc... but still..)?

Comment: The authoritative source would be the [Wasm spec](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/instructions.html#control-instructions). For a somewhat less precise but more compact grammar summary you can also look at the [reference interpreter README](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter#s-expression-syntax).

Comment: I suppose that wasm2c would be a possibility, but it won't give you significantly more readable code either. It merely compiles Wasm to C as is.